# Compile sass file inside browser

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, sass, user-input

I am trying to go about creating a system for my users where they can select particular SCSS files they would like to be included in the project. They do this through a browser. Once they check off all the related SCSS files, they want to hit a browser based "compile" button to generate the final CSS.

Is this possible? I have looked in the web for sometime but was unable to find anything. I know it's possible as I have seen it done for bootstrap, on their website.

Would someone be able to let me know if this is doable at all? I am not looking to implement any backend coding to do this, it needs to be done via javascript plugin of some sort.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you really need to do it in the client, [sass.js](https://github.com/medialize/sass.js) might help you. You can test it here: http://sass.js.org/